# Given a set of stabilizers, what is an efficient way to compute the logical states and logical operators?

Tags: stabilizer-code, stabilizer-state

Suppose I have $n$ qubits and I specify $n - k$ independent stabilizer generators. I have defined a Hilbert space with $k$ logical qubits. Moreover, there exist $2k$ operators that obey the Pauli commutation rules and represent logical $X$ and logical $Z$ on those $k$ qubits.

Is there a computationally efficient way to find these logical operators and logical states from the stabilizers alone?

---

As a concrete example, let's consider the $[[7,1,3]]$ Steane code. The stabilizers are:

$$
X_1X_2X_3X_4 \\
X_2X_3X_5X_6 \\
X_3X_4X_6X_7 \\ \
\\
Z_1Z_2Z_3Z_4 \\
Z_2Z_3Z_5Z_6 \\
Z_3Z_4Z_6Z_7 
$$

The answer should give me two logical operators $X_L = X_5X_6X_7$ and $Z_L=Z_5Z_6Z_7$ (or some other operator that is a multiple of these with the stabilizers) as well as the logical qubits $\vert 0\rangle_L$ and $\vert 1\rangle_L$ where

$$\begin{aligned}
|0\rangle_L= & \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}[|0000000\rangle+|1010101\rangle+|0110011\rangle+|1100110\rangle \\
& +|0001111\rangle+|1011010\rangle+|0111100\rangle+|1101001\rangle] \\
|1\rangle_L= & X_L|0\rangle_L
\end{aligned}$$

---

What is the "efficient" way to work this out for a general set of stabilizers and some larger number of physical qubits? I'm imagining really big codes with many stabilizers so I'd rather not do it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a construction that works for any CSS code (CSS code: all stabilizers either have all $Z$s or all $X$s). Let's start with $|0\rangle_L$ state. Let the stabilizers be given by $\{X^{\vec{v}_i}\}$ and $\{Z^{\vec{v}_i}\}$.

The state $|0\cdots 0\rangle$ of all physical qubits in the $|0\rangle$ state is already a $(+1)$ eigenstate of all $Z^{\vec{v}_i}$ and also $Z_L$. We want to project into the $(+1)$ eigenstates of the $X^{\vec{v}_i}$. This projector is given by $(1+X^{\vec{v}_i})/2$. Ignoring normalization, we can then write:

$$
|0\rangle_L=(1+X^{\vec{v}_1})\cdots (1+X^{\vec{v}_n})|0\cdots 0\rangle
$$

Note that this state is still a $(+1)$ eigenstate of $Z^{\vec{v}_i}$ and $Z_L$ because the projectors $(1+X^{\vec{v}_i})$ all commute with $Z^{\vec{v}_i}$ and $Z_L$.

This says to get $|0\rangle_L$, you take the uniform superposition over $|0\cdots 0\rangle$ and all possible combinations of bit-flips generated by the stabilizers $X^{\vec{v}_i}$. This predicts that for the Steane code, with $3$ $X$-stabilizers, you will have a superposition of $2^3$ basis states, one for each subset of the $X$ stabilizers. This is precisely what you found above.

Once you have $|0\rangle_L$ you can get $|1\rangle_L$ by acting with $X_L$.

Note that this projector trick also works for non-CSS codes, but it's a little harder to interpret the result in the $Z$ basis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see how to get the logical states but not yet how to get the logical operators. From the stabilizers alone, how does one work out $Z^i_L$ and $X^i_L$ (where $i$ represents the index of the logical qubit)? I know these are elements of the centralizer of the stabilizer group but I'm not sure how to actually compute them

Comment: @user1936752 Ah yes! I think the standard reference for that is still 4.1 of Gottesman's PhD thesis: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705052